# JavaScript DIV Editing Destroys Functionality of Other Elements

Tags: javascript, html

So my website is built using a company's software called Inksoft which leaves me very little to work in the way of customization. So I have to do many workarounds.

[Here is my site's homepage.](http://livecustom.com)

The header on top of the page only has two links right now. "Products" and "Design Studio". My goal is to add an "About Us" link and "Buyers Guide" to the header as well.

I cannot add new content to the header using Inksoft's backend. So I coded a workaround to replace the content of existing DIV's within the header to say and link to where I want them to go.

The only issue is, the responsive mobile-nav loses functionality when this is implemented. [As seen here on this test page.](https://livecustom.com/livecustom/stores/page/1000016/test_page?NoCache=1)

The test page has the About Us in the top header, added by the use of this code:

```
<script>
  $("#header-nav-designs").html('<document.write="<li id="header-nav-studio"><a href="/LiveCustom/Stores/Page/1000023/About_Us"><font color="#000000">About Us</font></a></li>');
</script>
```

So, the simplified question is: how do I implement this code without losing the responsive functionality of the nav bar?

Comment: I'm seeing error in console somewhere in the javascript you are trying to add 'Extra stuff' to an element with ID `divID` but it doesn't exist. Try removing that and see if the functionality is restored

Comment: are you injecting them into the mobile-nav-wrap section too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `.html` function will replace the HTML inside the target element. If you want to just append the one value, you likely want to `.append` to the element.

In addition, you aren't setting the HTML to a valid html string. You probably just want to get rid of the `<document.write="` at the beginning of the string. The rest of it looks fine with just a cursory glance.

So:

```
<script>
  $("#header-nav-designs").append('<li id="header-nav-studio"><a href="/LiveCustom/Stores/Page/1000023/About_Us"><font color="#000000">About Us</font></a></li>');
</script>
```

Edit:

After looking at it a little more, it appears as though the `$('#header-nav-designs')` that you are selecting is already an `<li>` which means you need to either select the parent `<ul>` list or you can use the jquery [.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function instead.

```
<script>
  $("#header-nav-designs").after('<li id="header-nav-studio"><a href="/LiveCustom/Stores/Page/1000023/About_Us"><font color="#000000">About Us</font></a></li>');
</script>
```

And as someone else commented above, you are getting an error on the page. It appears as though you are trying to get an element with the id `divID` and the appending some html to it, but there is no element with the id `divID` and so you are getting an error saying that you can't read the property `innerHTML of null` as the call to `document.getElementById` is returning null (element not found).

Comment: This does not answer the question. The hamburger menu functionality is gone after adding the new HTML. But I agree he should get rid of the document.write

Comment: @VincentNguyen it's probably like I said, he is replacing the html (not appending an element) from the menu with invalid html. Which would cause exactly what is seen.

Comment: The edit using the .after works perfectly! As seen here: https://livecustom.com/livecustom/stores/page/1000024/test_page_part_deux?NoCache=1

I just have to do some hover and font editing. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

Element id header-nav-designs witch your code is referring have CSS style on line 170:

```
#header-nav-designs {display:none;}
```

The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there. With `display:none;`

If I understand you correctly your code selector points to wrong element id. It should point `$(".header-nav > ul")`. `Document.write` is not needed inside jQuery you need to give only an valid html string as argument.

jQuery html function erase html that is all ready inside element and replace it with html string given as argument. You have to use append if you want to add more html but not remove what is allready in element.

```
$(".header-nav > ul").append('<li><a href="/link1"><font color="#000000">About Us</font></a></li>');
$(".header-nav > ul").append('<li><a href="/link2"><font color="#000000">Buyers Guide</font></a></li>');
```